# mdtheorem beamer counter changes at every pause

Tags: beamer, mdframed, pause

Here it is a Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz,nobreak]{mdframed}

\mdtheorem[innerlinewidth=0.5pt, %
roundcorner=4pt,linecolor=blue,innerleftmargin=16pt,
innerrightmargin=16pt,backgroundcolor=white, %
frametitlerule=true,frametitlebackgroundcolor=cyan,innertopmargin=\topskip,innerbottommargin=\topskip]{definizione}{Definizione}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A slide} 

\begin{definizione}[A definition]

My definition. 

\end{definizione}\pause

\begin{itemize}
\item A comment about definition;\pause
\item Another comment
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I want a single counter for the definition on each page, but it keeps changing the counter after pause or new overlay (with the same theorem).

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches:

- if you want to keep `mdframed`, you could use `\only<2->{\addtocounter{definizione}{-1}}` as a quick hack to get the correct number
- or simply use beamers own definition environment. The format/language of the title can be adjusted to match what you have now, the only thing which would be a bit more complicate would be the boarder around the block.

---

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz,nobreak]{mdframed}

\mdtheorem[innerlinewidth=0.5pt, %
roundcorner=4pt,linecolor=blue,innerleftmargin=16pt,
innerrightmargin=16pt,backgroundcolor=white, %
frametitlerule=true,frametitlebackgroundcolor=cyan,innertopmargin=\topskip,innerbottommargin=\topskip]{definizione}{Definizione}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\useinnertheme{rounded}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\uselanguage{itanlian}
\languagepath{italian}
\deftranslation[to=italian]{Definition}{Definizione}
\deftranslation[to=italian]{definition}{definizione}

\definecolor{theocolor}{RGB}{0,173,239}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=theocolor}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=theocolor!20!white}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
    {%
      \inserttheoremname
      \inserttheoremnumber
      \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else
      : \inserttheoremaddition\fi%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A slide} 
\only<2->{\addtocounter{definizione}{-1}}
\begin{definizione}[A definition]

My definition. 

\end{definizione}\pause

\begin{itemize}
\item A comment about definition;\pause
\item Another comment
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{B slide} 
\begin{definition}[A definition]

My definition. 

\end{definition}\pause

\begin{itemize}
\item A comment about definition;\pause
\item Another comment
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]